# Convert string to long long C?

Tags: c, string, casting

How can I convert a string to a long long in C?

I've got

```
char* example = "123";
```

I'd like to convert example to a long long so I'd want something like

```
long long n = example;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Tip: It should be `char const *`, since string literals are read-only. It'll save you plenty of headache later, or at least it'll save people who copy/paste your code and don't know C.

Answer (score 11):

Use the function `strtoll`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

char const * example = "123";

char * e;
errno = 0;

long long int n = strtoll(example, &e, 0);

if (*e != 0 || errno != 0) { /* error, don't use n! */ }
```

In fact, `e` will point to the next character after the converted sequence, so you can do even more sophisticated parsing with this. As it stands, we just check that the entire sequence has been converted. You can also inspect `errno` to see if an overflow occurred. See [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll) for details.

(For historical interest: `long long int` and `strtoll` were introduced in C99. They're not available in C89/90. Equivalent functions `strtol` / `strtoul` / `strtod` exist, though.)

Comment: Note that using `0` as the third argument ("base") to `strtoll()` would interpret the input string "0123" as octal, so you might prefer to use  base=10 explicitly.